# Why one of the predicates would lead to too big intermediate results?

Tags: sql, left-join, exasolution

I am trying to left-merge two small tables given by sub-select and get an error message:

```
One of the predicates would lead to too big intermediate results. Table date_rabges_table has more than 5000000 rows or is bigger than 5000000 KB
```

The query that I use is given here:

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        date
    from
        dates_table
    where
        to_date('2010-01-01') <= date
        and
        date <= to_date('2014-01-01')
    )
left join
    (
    select
        min_date, max_date
    from
        date_ranges_table
    where
        i_id = 7
        and
        j_id = 13
    )
on
    min_date <= date
    and
    date < max_date
;
```

Some more details:

1. The first sub-select gives just one column with dates between 2010-01-01 and 2014-01-01 (I think it is a bit more that 1400 dates)
2. The second sub-select gives a table with two columns and two rows.

> ```
> min_date    max_date 
> 2013-02-01    2013-05-01
> 2013-06-01    2013-07-01
> ```

I do not understand why I get the error message that I mentioned above. I am merging two tables that are small (about 1400 rows and exactly 2 row). The final results of left-join should not be larger than the table on the left. Where is the problem?

Comment: Probably depends on the specific database product. Can you edit and add a tag for it? I'd probably guess that it's [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle].

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm pretty sure that Oracle doesn't have such an error message.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I use exasolution.